# Open Layers 3 Modify End

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

### Issue

---

I have setup my map shown below with a source and a layer:

```
var features = new ol.Collection();
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ features: features }),
vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: vectorSource
}),
styles = {
    route: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            width: 4,
            color: [255, 120, 0, 0.8]
    })
}),
routeSR: new ol.style.Style ({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 6,
        color: [0, 0, 0, 0.8]
    })
}),
icon: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1],
        src: session.icon_url
        })
    })
};



//CREATE THE MAP AND STORE IN SESSION.
session.map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-5685003, -3504484],
        zoom: 11
    })
});
```

I have then setup a click event on the map that will Create a feature for that point to show a little icon. If this is the second point selected it will create a LineString between the two points. Both shown below:

**LineString**

```
function TestCreateLine() {
    var CoordsFromTo = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < session.points.length; i++) {
        CoordsFromTo.push(session.points[i][0])
    }

    var line = new ol.geom.LineString(CoordsFromTo);

    var feature = new ol.Feature(line);

    feature.setStyle(styles.route);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
}
```

**Feature**

```
function TestCreateFeature(coord) {
    var coords = coord.shift();

    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        id: coords,
        type: 'place',
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point((coord[0]))
    });
    feature.setId(coords);
    feature.setStyle(styles.icon);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
}
```

They both get added as a feature to the source. The issue I am currently facing is that I want to be able to Modify the route and have the new Co-ordinate passed to me.

At the moment I am using 'ModifyEnd' event but it seems to be returning me more than one co-ordinate.

```
session.interactions.modify.on('modifyend', function (e) {
    //IF YOUR MODIFYING AN OSRM ROUTE
    if (document.getElementById('Checkbox2').checked) {

    }
    //LINE STRING ROUTE
    else {

        session.points = [];

        var changedFeatures = e.features.getArray();
        var newFeature = changedFeatures[changedFeatures.length - 1];
        var ben = newFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        vectorSource.clear()


        for (var i = 0; i < ben.length; i++) {

                var newPointInformation = [];
                newPointInformation.push((CreateGuid() + CreateGuid() + "-" + CreateGuid() + "-4" + CreateGuid().substr(0, 3) + "-" + CreateGuid() + "-" + CreateGuid() + CreateGuid() + CreateGuid()).toLowerCase());
                newPointInformation.push(ben[i]);

                session.points.push(newPointInformation);
                TestCreateFeature(newPointInformation);

        }

        TestCreateLine();
    }

});
```

As you can see I tryed emptying the source features and re-building but the issue is not all the co-ordinates get returned back to me.

Can anyone help?